How should we really think about subobjects in a topos?
Scenesetting
Some define a subobject of $X$ as a monic $s \colon S \rightarrowtail X.$ For familiar reasons, though, most officially define a subobject of $X$ as an equivalence class $[s]$ of such monics. Assume we want to take the second line. [Added  I don't mean to imply that I think the second line is right: I'm interested in how the story best gets fleshed out if you take the common line of officially treating subobjects as equivalence classes.]
Now, in impoverished categories that don't know much about equivalence classes, a subobject of $X$ in $\mathsf{C}$ defined the second way needn't be part of the data of the category $\mathsf{C}$ itself. But what if $\mathsf{C}$ is a topos?
Then we have (for $r, s$ monics with target $X$) $r \simeq s$ iff $\chi_r = \chi_s$ where the $\chi$s are, of course, the characteristic arrows. So if, in a categorial spirit, all we essentially care about in talking of "equivalence classes" of widgets is having some whatnots which are equal when the associated widgets are equivalent, why not say that the likes of $\chi_s$ (for $s$ a monic with target $X$) just are the subobjects of $X$?
But perhaps we can do better. Given $s \colon S \rightarrowtail X$, define $s^{\star}\colon S \rightarrowtail 1 \times X$ in the obvious way. Then using the power object construction in our topos, we have the pullback

where $\widetilde{\chi_{s^\star}}\colon 1 \to \Omega^X$ is the exponential transpose.
Question I think it is fair to say that most of the usual book presentations which treat subobjects of $X$ in $\mathsf{C}$ as "equivalence classes" $[s]$ (with $s$ some monic into $X$) don't explicitly tell us where these subobjects might be found in $\mathsf{C}$.${}^1$ But, noting that $\widetilde{\chi_{r^\star}} = \widetilde{\chi_{s^\star}}$ iff $r \simeq s$, why not explicitly identify $[s]$ -- at least in a topos -- with $\widetilde{\chi_{s^\star}}$?
And if we identify subobjects with such arrows we have, nicely, that subobjects of $X$ are global elements of $\Omega^X$, and $\Omega^X$ is there to play the role of $Sub(X)$, a set-sized "collection" of equivalence classes of monics into $X$. What's not to like [if you want a story about implementing equivalence classes.]

1. Or have I missed a good treatment in one of the standard texts?
 

The definition of subobjects as isomorphism classes of monics makes sense in any category, so it is more general. If you have a subobject classifier, then the set of subobjects of $X$ is indeed (identified with) the Hom-set $X \to \Omega$. I don't know what you mean by "where these subobjects might be found in $\mathsf{C}$" or "in impoverished categories that don't know much about equivalence classes", and I don't know what your exponential transpose is achieving.

@NaïmFavier Of course, of course, the definition as isomorphism classes makes sense with respect to any category. But we might then reasonably ask, are the subobjects of objects of $\mathsf{C}$ as thus defined to be found among the data (the objects and arrows) of $\mathsf{C}$ itself?

I still don't know what that means. The data of a category is a collection of objects and a family of Hom-sets equipped with certain operations and satisfying certain laws. From this data, you can define the class/partial order of subobjects of a given object $X$.

Why not identity $[s]$ with $\chi_s$? Using the subobject concept as monomorphisms into the object is very key, the fact we have alternative ways of encoding this is very useful but you still want to be able to refer to a monomorphism $A\hookrightarrow B$ as a subobject! And this more directly fits the subset intuition anyhow. I'm not sure what the question actually is. What do you mean by "[where should these subobjects be] found"? They are found exactly by their representative maps $A\hookrightarrow B$. And I'd rather say we can encode (but not equate) the subobjects with their $\chi$

@NaïmFavier Ah. Perhaps I am betraying that I am wedded to the kind of definition given by Awodey ( Lawvere & Schanuel,  McLarty, etc.) that has the data of a category as some objects, and some arrows, satisfying the usual conditions. Then the story about hom-sets gets more complicated. On that sort of approach, what the "exponential transpose" story is achieving is that we have data in our topos $\mathsf{E}$, even if we suppose that hom-sets (as opposed to virtual collections) are best thought of as kosher sets living in $\mathsf{Set}$.

@NaïmFavier But thanks, your reaction has helpfully highlighted something I dimly hadn't joined up the dots about -- that what we build into our preferred defintion of a category will make a difference here.

@FShrike "Why not identify [] with ?" I do, on Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays :)  Or rather, with you exactly, I'd put it in terms of  encoding.

I don't really understand your question, and in particular I don't really understand these bits which seem to be key to some kind of philosophical objection you have:

a subobject of $X$ in $\mathsf{C}$ defined the second way needn't be part of the data of the category $\mathsf{C}$ itself.


"equivalence classes" $[s]$ (with $s$ some monic into $X$) don't explicitly tell us where these subobjects might be found in $\mathsf{C}$.

The way I would talk about this is not specific to toposes and does not require the existence of a subobject classifier. It is that, to my mind, the real lesson of the categorical point of view is that a subobject should be thought of as a monic $S \hookrightarrow X$, full stop. There is actually no need to take equivalence classes.
These naturally form a structure only slightly more complicated than a poset, namely a preorder, but reasoning about preorders is not really any more complicated than reasoning about posets. A preorder is just a poset where some objects can be isomorphic, in exactly the way that monics can be. Among other benefits, this gives you direct access to categorical operations on subobjects: intersections are the pullback of two literal monomorphisms in the ambient category, and so forth.
This point of view leads to the idea that subobjects can naturally be thought of as special objects in a larger category, namely the slice category of all maps $Y \to X$. In fact they are precisely the subterminal objects.
Then it's a pleasant exercise to work through any particular application you care about of the concept of a subobject (subgroups in group theory and so forth) and notice that you never need to work with equivalence classes of monics and the arguments go through just fine with monics. If you want to do something like count subobjects then you can explicitly pass to isomorphism classes but that's no different than when we, say, count isomorphism classes of irreducible representations of a group.

Yes! When I said "Assume we want to take the second line", I didn't mean to sound as if I was recommending taking the second line.  (But I did sound that way, I realise!) I was/am interested in how the story about the equivalence classes should go if you are one of the many (majority?) who do officially take the second line. But yes, I'm very much inclined to go your way and stick with just saying subobjects are monics.

@Peter: then I still don't really understand your question; what are you asking?

Given two subobjects of $X$ (literal monics, not equivalence classes), you get their intersection as a pullback. But pullbacks are defined only up to isomorphism. So if you want the pullback to be a literal monic, it seems you'll need to either admit a whole isomorphism class of monics or pick one monic from that equivalence class. The first option puts you back in the realm of equivalence class, from which you had  escaped, and the second requires an arbitrary choice. (I like the axiom of choice, but not enough to be happy with it here.)

I didn't mean to be obscure! To put it baldly ... Suppose, just suppose, you do take the line that subobjects are equivalence classes of monics. It seems reasonable (at least for a rich enough category like a topos) to want a subobject of an object in your category, so understood, to itself be something belonging to that category. If so, what's the best story? @NaïmFavier has it that such isomorphism classes are members of the hom-set $X \to \Omega$ so are arrows in category like $\chi_s$. Fine. But this isn't usually spelt out. Because it is too obvious??

@AndreasBlass Wouldn't the subobjects as literal monics line be that the relevant pullback diagram defines what it is for one monic to be AN intersection of two others, rather than their unique intersection? (Different pullbacks giving different but isomorphic intersections.)

@PeterSmith That would be reasonable if "AN intersection" is acceptable, but note that the answer refers to "the pullback".

@Andreas: the convention here, as I understand it, is that category theorists are fine with using the word "the" to label something which is unique up to unique isomorphism, as any construction defined using universal properties must be. This issue already appears when thinking about the product or coproduct as a functor and stuff like that. I'm not aware of a completely satisfying way to deal with it but it's no more or less satisfying than this much more general categorical phenomenon. The POV I advocate here is exactly treating the collection of subobjects as a category.

@Peter: I still don't understand you. What do you mean by "wanting a subobject to itself be something belonging to that category"? Specifically, what does "belong" mean here? As for arrows to the subobject classifier, that is just the definition of the subobject classifier, so I still don't understand what you're asking about.

(Of course, one of the nice things about a (locally small) topos is that it's "well-powered": each subobject preorder has a small set of representatives of the equivalence classes, while it would be rare for each subobject preorder to be small itself.)

@Daniel: sure, but again, this is no more or less strange than what happens when we consider small vs. essentially small categories such as the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces. It's all very familiar category stuff.
